# ListView android работа с clickListener

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте, вопрос в следующем мне нужно по id ArrayList'a получить объект,
чтобы вытащить id я использую onItemClickListener который получает id и передает методу get. Но при компиляции возникает ошибка. Почему?

Класс из которого передаю:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(
  new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
        long itemId = parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
);
```

Класс в котором получаю:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    long item = intent.getExtras().getLong("itemId");
    int itemId = (int) item ;

    Log.d("artyom", String.valueOf(itemId));

    storage.read(itemId);

    Poster filmName = storage.read(itemId);
    name.setText(filmName.getName());
```

Класс хранилище:

```
public Poster read (int id) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
  return posterList.get(id);
}
```

Стактрейс ошибки:

```
01-21 08:42:43.470 2359-2359/com.wooppay.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wooppay.test, PID: 2359
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wooppay.test/com.wooppay.test.activities.DisplayActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.wooppay.test.storage.ArrayStorage.read(ArrayStorage.java:32)
    at com.wooppay.test.activities.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Вот так добавляю элементы в список:

```
     storage.create(0,new Poster("Заголовок1", "Подзаголовок1"));
    storage.create(1,new Poster("Заголовок2", "Подзаголовок2"));
    storage.create(2,new Poster("Заголовок3", "Подзаголовок3"));
    storage.create(3,new Poster("Заголовок4", "Подзаголовок4"));
    storage.create(4,new Poster("Заголовок5", "Подзаголовок5"));
```

size выдает что в списке 5 элементов

```
     public void create(int id, Poster poster){

    posterList.add(id, poster);


}
```

Comment: стектрейс ошибки приложите в вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff я извиняюсь, ошибка не при компиляции а в эмуляторе просто крашится приложение при нажатии на элемент списка, если закоментировать storage.read(itemId), все работает

Comment: в вкладке logcat IDE будет стектрейс, что именно стало причиной остановки приложения, выложите его сюда.

Comment: в вашем списке posterList нет элементов (обращение к 4 элементу, а размер списка - 0)

Comment: @pavlofff возможно ли такое, что при переходе в другое активити список обнуляется? когда попробовал добавить индексы приложение начало валиться сразу же, с той же ошибкой. Дополнил код в вопросе

Comment: вы передаете этот список из одного активити в другое?

Comment: @pavlofff да, спасибо за ответы, вопрос решен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public Poster read (int id) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
     return posterList.get(id);
 }
```

у вас метод пробрасывает исключение и не обрабатывается (например try/catch), на нем и падает, но уже в другом месте, те DisplayActivity.
Попробуйте убрать throws IndexOutOfBoundsException это позволит вам увидеть ошибку, после убедитесь, что posterList правильно инициализируется и при вызове метода имеет индекс. По логам видно, что у него размер сейчас 0, а вы пытаетесь выбрать 4.

Comment: но стектрейс сообщает, что обращение к четвертому элементу, когда размер списка - 0. то есть причина не в исключении, а в том, что в списке нет элементов

Comment: ну исключение поставили видимо, ибо IDE детекнула что список пуст, нужно причину искать, я в ответе добавил. Явно в этом причина, а уж что там с List происходит не видно.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei дополнил в вопросе, список создается правильно, индексы есть, но при переходе в другое активити как будто обнуляется

Comment: ну а где у вас сам Storage живет? Скорей всего у вас разные экземпляры этого класса) в первом вы пишите new и во втором вы создаете ещё 1 экземпляр, но уже с пустым списком, вам нужно использовать первый. Можете перед read сделать проверку, у storage например getSize, хотя по логам очевидно, что список пуст.

Comment: Благодарю, ArrayStorage был классом вызывл с помощью new,  сделал enum'ом и вызывал ArrayStorage.INSTANCE.read, например.